# Got error message in LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

I've got this error:

```
Error message is :: "Error occured during query execution: (LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/3sch.jofcial.txtgymCN5' REPLACE INTO TABLE `prod_sch` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES (No_ ,Model_Code,Model_Name ,Lot_No_ ,Start_Seq_No_ ,Quantity ,Lot_Quantity ,Line_Code ,Line_Name ,@var10, Shift_No1,@var12,Shift_No2,@var14,Production_Mngm_Type,Model_Group,Model_Category,Actual_Results,MPS_Mngm_Code, Production_Mngm_Code,Comment) SET Production_Start_Date=STR_TO_DATE(@var10,'%m/%d/%Y'), Production_Finish_Date=STR_TO_DATE(@var12,'%m/%d/%Y'), Due_date=STR_TO_DATE(@var14,'%m/%d/%Y')): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version";
```

After try this syntax:

```
$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '3sch.jofcial.txt');  // make temporary file name
$fp = fopen($temp_file, "wb");          // open temprary file
if (!$fp) die(_ERROR14);
fwrite($fp, $httpfile);                         // copy to temporary file from schedule file
fclose($fp);
chmod($temp_file, 0644);                        // file mode change for read only

$sql="TRUNCATE TABLE `prod_sch`";
$res=mysql_query($sql) ;//or _doError(_ERROR30 . ' (<small>' . htmlspecialchars($sql) . '</small>): ' . mysql_error() );  // submit SQL to MySQL $
$sql="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$temp_file."' REPLACE INTO TABLE `prod_sch` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES "; // FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '\"'$
$sql.="(No_ ,Model_Code,Model_Name ,Lot_No_ ,Start_Seq_No_ ,Quantity ,Lot_Quantity ,Line_Code ,Line_Name ,@var10, ";
$sql.="Shift_No1,@var12,Shift_No2,@var14,Production_Mngm_Type,Model_Group,Model_Category,Actual_Results,MPS_Mngm_Code, ";
$sql.="Production_Mngm_Code,Comment) ";
$sql.="SET Production_Start_Date=STR_TO_DATE(@var10,'%m/%d/%Y'), ";
$sql.="Production_Finish_Date=STR_TO_DATE(@var12,'%m/%d/%Y'), ";
$sql.="Due_date=STR_TO_DATE(@var14,'%m/%d/%Y')";

$res=mysql_query($sql) or _doError(_ERROR30 . ' (<small>' . htmlspecialchars($sql) . '</small>): ' . mysql_error() );  // submit SQL to MySQL and$
unlink($temp_file);
```

This error happen after restore the backup file into new server. From the error message I can see that the temporary file already created.

---

**EDIT**

I have try:

`mysql --load-infile -u root -p pwd DBname`

then try to put the query above inside `>mysql`, this query can work.
But, why if i using php it doesn't?

try to edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf:
`add local-infile = 1`
still can't work.
this the [php page](http://pastebin.com/N2jpTdvW)

Comment: What is the version of your MySQL server?

Comment: @Bjoern: this my version `Server version: 5.5.22-0ubuntu1`

Comment: just information, this problem happen after move to new ubuntu server, and I don't change anything in here. Just restore whole file into new server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problem solved**

Just change:

```
$dbc=mysql_connect(_SRV, _ACCID, _PWD) or die(_ERROR15.": ".mysql_error());
```

Into :

```
$dbc=mysql_connect(_SRV, _ACCID, _PWD,false,128) or die(_ERROR15.": ".mysql_error());
```

Tadaaa...all error is gone!!

Comment: Can anyone add PDO to this answer?

Comment: @BobKruithof: post your PDO, so i could try.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data-local.html):

> If [`LOAD DATA LOCAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) is disabled, either in the server or the client, a client that attempts to issue such a statement receives the following error message:
>
> `ERROR 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`

Comment: still confuse how to do first, enabling load data?

Comment: @nunu It depends how the server and client is configured. Is this in a shared hosting environment or a dedicated box? How much control do you have over the server configuration? All the info you need is in the first link in my answer - look at the second list, below `To deal with these problems, we changed how LOAD DATA LOCAL is handled as of MySQL 3.23.49 and MySQL 4.0.2 (4.0.13 on Windows):`

Comment: I try using mysql command in ubuntu terminal and the query can work. But, why in my php file it doesn't?